# Why does a boxplot in ggplot requires axis x and y?

Tags: r

I have a variable ceroonce which is number of schools per county (integers) in 2011. When I plot it with `boxplot()` it only requires the ceroonce variable. A boxplot is then retrieved in which the y axis is the number of schools and the x axis is... the "factor" ceroonce. But in `ggplot`, when using `geom_boxplot`, it requires me to input both x and y axis, but I just want a boxplot of ceroonce. I have tried inputing ceroonce as both the x and y axis. But then a weird boxplot is retrieved in which the y axis is the number of schools but the x axis (which should be the factor variable) is also the number of schools? I am assuming this is very basic statistics, but I am just confused. I am attaching the images hoping this will clarify my question.

This is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(escuelas, aes(x=ceroonce, y=ceroonce))+geom_boxplot()
boxplot(escuelas$ceroonce)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no fancy statistics happening here. `boxplot` is simply assuming that since you've given it a single vector, that you want a single box in your boxplot. `ggplot` and `geom_histogram` simply don't make that assumption.

If you want a bit less typing, you can do this:

```
qplot(y=escuelas$ceroonce, x= 1, geom = "boxplot")
```

ggplot2 will automatically create a vector of 1s equal in length to the length of escuelas$ceroonce

Comment: thank you! yes, i found out that stat_boxplot and thus geom_boxplot require x and y arguments... and that you cannot simply define x (as with boxplot())

Comment: thanks for this response. i think this is a rather unintuitive behaviour from ggplot. A lot of people will likely not group their data.

Answer (score 29):

```
ggplot(escuelas, aes(x="ceroonce", y=ceroonce))+geom_boxplot()
```

ggplot will interpret the character string "ceroonce" as a vector with the same length as the ceroonce column and it will give the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This could work for you:

```
ggplot(escuelas, aes(x= "", y=ceroncee)) + geom_boxplot()
```